# VBA listbox selections not resetting when listbox is called again

Tags: vba, forms, listbox

I've got some code where the user has to multi-select items from a 2-column listbox. These items are variables which will later be plotted, and each have their own units (i.e. °C, °F, etc.). If the user selects items which have different units, an error message appears telling them to reselect.

The problem I'm having is that after the user reselects, it seems the initial selections are still there, because when the plot is generated I can see those variables being plotted. Here's what I've tried without any success:

```
If InStr(header, yUnit) = 0 Then 'this is the check to see if the selections use different units
    MsgBox "Error! y variable selections contain different units. Please choose again"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveChart.Delete 'Delete the chart which is currently being constructed
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'Method 1:
    Unload FormatChart
    
    FormatChart.UserForm_Initialize 'FormatChart is the form in which the listbox is contained.
                                    'UserForm_Initialize is the subroutine which constructs the listbox
    
    FormatChart.Show
    
    'Method 2:
    With FormatChart.ListBox1
        For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1

            If .Selected(x) Then
             .Selected(x) = False
            End If

        Next x
    End With

    FormatChart.Show

End If


'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I just have to use the following:

```
FormatChart.Show
Exit Sub
```

I believe what was happening was that the subroutine would continue to run, even though after I showed the form again I had an "Enter" button which would call the subroutine again, possibly resulting in it grabbing variables from the previous, still active, instance of it, or that multiple instances of that subroutine were running, not sure... anyway I'm just happy to end this headache :)